# Snakecase in a retrofit call with gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am using the original retrofit to call the Instagram api. The call returns this reponse

```
{ "data" : [ { "attribution" : null,
    "caption" : { "created_time" : "1460953831",
        "from" : { "full_name" : "Edward ♕",
            "id" : "282525924",
            "profile_picture" : "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12519400_165282517199271_1363863979_a.jpg",
            "username" : "manlike_eddy"
          },
        "id" : "17847512245075242",
        "text" : "Oh girl"
      },
    "comments" : { "count" : 1,
        "data" : [ { "created_time" : "1460953885",
              "from" : { "full_name" : "Edward ♕",
                  "id" : "282525924",
                  "profile_picture" : "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12519400_165282517199271_1363863979_a.jpg",
                  "username" : "manlike_eddy"
                },
              "id" : "17847512257075242",
              "text" : "#love #TagsForLikes #TagsForLikesApp #instagood #me #smile #follow #cute #photooftheday #tbt #followme #girl #beautiful #happy #picoftheday #instadaily #food #swag #amazing #TFLers #fashion #igers #fun #summer #instalike #bestoftheday #smile #like4like #friends #instamood"
            } ]
      },
    "created_time" : "1460953831",
    "filter" : "Normal",
    "id" : "1230892414266144399_282525924",
    "images" : { "low_resolution" : { "height" : 320,
            "url" : "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/12965764_932183320233898_1928407701_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTIzMDg5MjQxNDI2NjE0NDM5OQ%3D%3D.2.l",
            "width" : 320
          },
        "standard_resolution" : { "height" : 640,
            "url" : "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12965764_932183320233898_1928407701_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTIzMDg5MjQxNDI2NjE0NDM5OQ%3D%3D.2.l",
            "width" : 640
          },
        "thumbnail" : { "height" : 150,
            "url" : "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c257.0.565.565/12950340_1566398773652655_1170974002_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTIzMDg5MjQxNDI2NjE0NDM5OQ%3D%3D.2.c",
            "width" : 150
          }
      },
    "likes" : { "count" : 0,
        "data" : [  ]
      },
    "link" : "https://www.instagram.com/p/BEVAiEVDnaP/",
    "location" : null,
    "tags" : [ "beautiful",
        "cute",
        "fashion",
        "love",
        "summer",
        "food",
        "instalike",
        "tbt",
        "tagsforlikesapp",
        "igers",
        "follow",
        "instadaily",
        "instamood",
        "friends",
        "girl",
        "me",
        "swag",
        "like4like",
        "tflers",
        "followme",
        "instagood",
        "tagsforlikes",
        "amazing",
        "bestoftheday",
        "fun",
        "smile",
        "photooftheday",
        "picoftheday",
        "happy"
      ],
    "type" : "image",
    "user" : { "full_name" : "Edward ♕",
        "id" : "282525924",
        "profile_picture" : "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12519400_165282517199271_1363863979_a.jpg",
        "username" : "manlike_eddy"
      },
    "user_has_liked" : false,
    "users_in_photo" : [  ]
  } ],

}
```

}

As you can see some of the labels are using snakecase, such as `standard_resolution`. When I plug this data into [Json Pogo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) it creates two classes for `standard_resolution`. One named `StandardResolution` and one `StandardResolution`. When I call `.getStandardResolution()` on the respective object null is returned, even though it should have valid data.

Comment: i think your json is incorrect format, in second last line remove comma

Comment: @USKMobility Yes, there is some extra metadata that clogged up the post and didn't feel the need to include. Here is a pastebin of the full call: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Hreybadj)

Comment: how did you convert json to java object using gson, add code

Comment: Using this retrofit call  

`@GET("tags/{tag-name}/media/recent/?access_token=TOKEN")
    Call<InstaPosts> getPostsWithHashtag(@Path("tag-name") String tagname);`

Comment: what is the name of two different classes for standard_resolution. But when i create POJO only one class is created with named StandardResolution.java